# Change one field in an array using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of objects, where one field is a boolean field called includeInReport.  In a certain case, I want to default that to always be true.  I know it's as easy as doing this:

```
foreach (var item in awards)
{
    item.IncludeInReport = true;
}
```

But is there an equilivent way to do this with linq?  It's more to satisfy my curiosity then anything...  My first thought was to do this...

```
awards.Select(a => new Award{ IncludeInReport = true, SomeFiled = a.SomeField, .... }
```

But since I have a few fields in my object, I didn't want to have to type out all of the fields and it's just clutter on the screen at that point.  Thanks!

Comment: List.ForEach is generally froned upon as others have noted below. Here's a good article going into it as well: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ForEach is sort of linq:

```
awards.ForEach(item => item.IncludeInReport = true);
```

But Linq is not about updating values. So you are not using the right tool.

---

Let me quantify "sort of linq". ForEach is **not** Linq, but a method on `List<T>`. However, the syntax is similar to Linq.

Comment: `ForEach` is a method implemented in `List` so it would work only if awards is a `List<Award>`

Comment: Not sure why the -1?  Sure .ForEach might not be 'pure' but it will work for what the op wants.  Just do a .ToList() first.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the correct code:

```
awards = awards.Select(a => {a.IncludeInReport = true; return a;});
```

LINQ follows functional programming ideas and thus doesn't want you to change (mutate) existing variables.

So instead in the code above we generate a new list (haven't changed any existing values) and then overwrite our original list (this is outside LINQ so we no longer care about functional programming ideas).

Answer (score 6):

Since you are starting with an array, you can use the [`Array.ForEach` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2.aspx):

```
Array.ForEach(awards, a => a.IncludeInReport = true);
```

This isn't LINQ, but in this case you don't need LINQ. As others have mentioned, you can't mutate items via LINQ. If you have a `List<T>` you could use [its `ForEach` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) in a similar fashion. Eric Lippert discusses this issue in more depth here:  ["foreach" vs "ForEach"](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

There is no mutating method available in Linq. Linq is useful for querying, ordering, filtering, joining, and projecting data. If you need to mutate it, you already have a very clean, clear method of doing so: your loop.

`List<T>` exposes a `ForEach` method to write something that reminds you of Linq (but isn't). You can then provide an `Action<T>` or some other delegate/function that applies your mutation to each element in turn. (Ahmed Mageed's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9368937/414076) also mentions the slightly different `Array.ForEach` method.) You can write your own extension method to do the same with `IEnumerable<T>` (which would then be generally more applicable than either aforementioned method and also be available for your array). But I encourage you to simply keep your loop, it's not exactly dirty.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
awards.AsParallel().ForAll(item => item.IncludeInReport = true)
```

That makes that action parallel if possible.